# Users cannot access after extracting database

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server

I have extracted data from SQL 2012 to a new copy in SQL 2012 in same PC as well, in original database users can access website using their username and password, but when I try to use copied database, users cannot access into website.

Notes:

1- If I add a new user into copied data, it works fine. But If i try to access using extracted data, it will not work and no error shows.
2-original database connection was using server authentication and the copied database is using windows authentication. May I know what caused that and how to solve ?

Comment: is the database name the same?

Comment: sorry, they are using the same name. I made their names same just now, but still same issue

Comment: is the instance of the sql the same? and if they are using windows authentication, is the user and password the same? Coz for this, the only issue here is the connection string and nothing more, if you really just copied the whole thing, all you need to check is the connection string nothing more

Comment: the instance name is not the same, original database was using windows authentication and the new database is using windows authentication.

Comment: then change the instance name in the connection string in your website..